# Kusto (KQL) best way to get the most recent event?

Tags: kql

I need to write a KQL to count the number of occurrences of an event and then to evaluate as specific column value in the most recent event based on TimeGenerated - this question is for the second part.

I found the arg_max function could be used to get the most recent event - though most examples of its application I saw were much more complex than my scenario:

```
T | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *)
```

Then I found another way simply using sort and take:

```
T | sort by TimeGenerated desc | take 1
```

Is there any best practice to get most recent event (would prefer to follow if there is)?  I suspect the function might be more efficient - however in my case the datasets to be evaluated will be relatively small so any time difference is negligible.  The sort/take approach appears to be more human readable.

Answer (score 0):

> *in my case the datasets to be evaluated will be relatively small so any time difference is negligible. The sort/take approach appears to be more human readable.*

the best option for these considerations is the [`top` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/topoperator)

e.g.

```
let lower_bound = ago(1d); // adjust & use this, if you can
T
| where TimeGenerated < lower_bound // remove this, if you can't use it
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc
```

or, if you set and use the `lower_bound`:

```
T
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc
```